# Linearization of control system

Tags: stability-theory, linearization

How can i linearize the following system ?

State equations:

$ x'_1 = (x_1-2)x_2 - 2x_2 $

$ x'_2 =-(x_1-2)^2 + x_2 + u -1 $

Output equation:

$ y = x_1 $

assume the eq. point : $ \tilde x=[2 ,0]^T$ and $\tilde u=1$

I know the teory, but pratically, how can i find the linearized equation ?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
A &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \Big\vert_{x=x_e,u=0} = 
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}  \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1}   & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_2 & x_1-4  \\
-2(x_1-2) & 1
\end{bmatrix}_{x=(2,0)}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -2  \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \\
B &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \Big\vert_{x=x_e} = 
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial u}    \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial u}    \\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0   \\
1   \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
The linearized system is then 
\begin{align}
\dot{x}&=Ax+Bu \\
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}_1 \\ \dot{x}_2
\end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -2  \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
0   \\
1   \\
\end{bmatrix}
u
\end{align}